# Есть ли какие либо сервисы для проверки php, ajax, jquery на ошибки/правильность написания ?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Интересуют любые сервисы, которые облегчают работу.

Comment: firebug, ошибки на экране :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не до конца понимаю, что вы имеете в виду, но думаю это может вам пригодиться:

- http://jsfiddle.net/
- http://ideone.com/

Answer (score 0):

Я только учусь ,но думаю,что можно юзать  PHPdesigner там подсвет текста есть для PHP,CSS,HTML,JavaScript,SQL и остальное.Он защищает от простых ошибок.Также там есть много разных функций,которые облегчают жизнь(которых я ещо не познал))  ).И конечно мозила  с консолем ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

php в начале файла пропишите -- error_reporting(E_ALL);
а для дебага js, firebug в помощь.

если не знаете что это такое, гугл в помощь.